# VB.NET How to get the last value from a Column in a DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a DataTable called DTPerson like this:

```
Name - - - - - Age - - - - - Number
John - - - - - 16  - - - - - 1234567
Mike - - - - - 25  - - - - - 1231231
```

I need to retrieve the last field from the Column "Name" in DTPerson.
I want label1.text = Mike
I've looked everywhere and could only find examples for Datasets so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: `DataSets` dont directly contain data (oddly), they contain `DataTables`, so whatever you found may apply.  But the data for a person will be in the rows, the part you want will be  **at** the position indicated by the column.

Comment: label1.Text = DTPerson.Rows(i).Item("Name").ToString() Doesn't work :/

Comment: Also doesn't work. This is my For loop:                For i As Integer = 0 To DTPerson.Rows.Count
label1.Text = DTPerson.Rows(i).Item("Name").ToString()
                Next

Comment: Updated above comment. That's my for loop and when it executes it says "There was no position found at row 2". When I replace For i As Integer = 0 To DTPerson.Rows.Count to For i As Integer = 0 To DTPerson.Rows.Count - 1 it just displays "John" but I need Mike :/

Comment: Why loop and set the labels text? Doesn't make sense. In the end it will only show the last record...

Comment: If u use the code I sent it doesn't work? Also remove the `-1`

Comment: I was doing a few other stuff in the For statement aswell, so I decided I can put this into it too, but at the end of the day you're right. I will try it without the loop.

Comment: Try this one `DTPerson.Rows(DTPerson.Rows.Count -1).Item("Name").ToString()`

Comment: Your code sends me the same error as mine ("There was no position found at row 2".) EDIT: Also when I put in -1 in your code it successfully returns "Mike" but removing the -1 just sends the error message..

Comment: Then you only have 1 record/row it seems... We tried both ways so I know now u only have 1 record.

Comment: I loaded everything into a datagridview and it's showing both John and Mike.. EDIT: I added a new record: Simon , 30 , 1234632. And when I use .Count - 1 it returns Mike. Without -1 it receives an error:  "There was no position found at row 3"

Comment: Lol so your looping through a datagridview and not a datatable?

Comment: No I loaded everything into a datagridview to make sure that John and Mike actually existed.. Also I updated my previous comment. Btw thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
  DTPerson.Rows(DTPerson.Rows.Count -1).Item("Name").ToString()
```